# How can I quickview (mac) a file?

Tags: macos

I would like to write a plist that would call quicklook to display a csv file containing weather data every morning at 7 AM.
How do I launch quickview on a file? Can I do it with python's subprocess.Popen?

I found the quicklook process on activity monitor but I don't know how I would call it or if its about quicklook or spotlight.

According to the formula i need to provide some code so this is the plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.my-script</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/al/Documents/wget/my-script.sh</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Hour</key>
                <integer>7</integer>
                <key>Minute</key>
                <integer>01</integer>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I would like the script `/Users/al/Documents/wget/my-script.sh` to call quicklook on my csv file

Comment: Try running `qlmanage -p YourFile.csv` in Terminal. If that does what you want, you can do exactly the same thing from Python's `subprocess()`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to show anything